# Simple way to convert a Pandas Series for integer comparison

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, where-clause, multiple-columns

I have the very simple. following code, and would like to select all the teams that have a highest_ranking of 1.

```
import pandas as pd
table = pd.read_table('team_rankings.dat')
table.head()

rank    team    rating  highest_rank    highest_rating  
0   1   Germany 2097    1   2205    
1   2   Brazil  2086    1   2161    
2   3   Spain   2011    1   2147    
3   4   Portugal    1968    2   1991    
4   5   Argentina   1967    1   2128

type((table['highest_rank'])) 
pandas.core.series.Series

table.loc[(table['highest_rank']) < 2]
```

then gives me a

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

since some highest_rank enteries are '-'. Urgh. What's a simple way to perform this (integer) selection??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User `pd.to_numeric` with `errors ='coerce'` i.e

```
df.loc[(pd.to_numeric(df['highest_rank'],errors='coerce')) < 2]
```

Output:

```
  rank       team  rating  highest_rank  highest_rating
0     1    Germany    2097             1            2205
1     2     Brazil    2086             1            2161
2     3      Spain    2011             1            2147
4     5  Argentina    1967             1            2128
```

Answer (score 4):

You can parse the "-" as a NaN-value. That might help you for more future tasks.

```
table = pd.read_table('team_rankings.dat', na_values="-")
```

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Read the docs, `keep_default_na` defaults to true so it is automatically appended. Your version is unnecessarily code smell.

Comment: @MaxU during the last half year I spent too much time always reading the docs and it feels like they have a solution for everything...

Comment: and @npross, with my solution you will have integers all the time, you will never need to cast them for any future task. only when you want to visualize the table, you need to replace the NaN values with the minus (if that is how you want to visualize it)